# How to update variables while page in Infinite loop in PHP?

Tags: php, session, cookies, infinite-loop

I have something like this :

```
<?php
  $perform_check = 1; #Checks data with ID : 1
  while(true)
  {
    #code
  }
?>
```

*But some data must be updated in this process, is it possible to update this data from another document?*

I tried something like this :

**index.php**

```
<?php
  setcookie("data", 19, time()+3600);
?>
```

and

**loop.php**

```
<?php
  while(true)
  {
    if($perform_check!=$_COOKIE[data]) $perform_check = $_COOKIE[data];
    #rest of code
    flush();
    sleep(0.3);
  }
?>
```

But it doesn't work. I also tried `$_SESSION` but the page crashes on `session_start()`.

Is it somehow possible?

Comment: Have you tried storing it in a table or file and re-reading it each loop iteration?

Comment: @jprofitt I thought there is a better way (like with COOKIE) to do that.

Comment: why do you want to use a infinity loop ?

Comment: @VinceV. I want to use this as an alternative to "node.js" or to "Comet". In my case the file containing the loop is loaded with Ajax and then I update information on the site using "xmlhttpreq.responseText"

Comment: Instead of using the while loop why not just an ajax request that requests at like every 10 seconds instead of a while loop ?

Comment: @VinceV. 10 seconds is too much.. I will have also a chat like system, I don't want to wait 10 seconds for a message... is not a good idea to use ajax to send requests like each second, because it will slow up a whole page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies are sent as a [HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) when PHP is sending a response through the web server (for example Apache2).

All HTTP headers are sent before any output. If you output anything, headers are sent (including the [set-cookie header](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt)) before the output.

After you `flush()` the first time you can no longer set cookies or other headers.

If you want a progress indicator or updates, you need to initiate whatever operation you are doing using javascript and do polling at an interval. In the process with the loop you need to save the progress in a shared memory, in a file or in a database (in this order of preference), then read that data using the process started by javascript progress check/updates check.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the existence of a file to flag the ending of the process.  For example, create a lock file,

```
$lock_file = <some unique name>
fopen($lock_file, 'w') or die("can't open file");
while ( file_exists($lock_file)) {

.
.
doStuff();
.
.

}
```

If the file is removed by some other process, it should terminate.

Comment: But I don't want to stop the loop. I will stop when user will close website

Answer (score 1):

I think a while loop isn't doing any good here. you should look into [php websocket implementation](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/). It's an implementation in PHP to have websockets and to have a open connection with your user. If you have that you can manage things with listeners on both sides.

Comment: unfortunately my go daddy shared web hosting doesn't allow me to create a socket server

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value to change while your code is looping, you need to check if the value has changed within the loop, not before.

A cookie or session will only work if the same user/browser is running both scripts. Writing to a file or database is the more usual approach.

Comment: oh sorry, edited my post. In my original files the check is inside while(){}, but it don't work.

Comment: "A cookie or session will only work if the same user/browser is running both scripts." - I tried on the same browser, but it didn't worked for me. For "COOKIES" it had no changes, but for "SESSION" all pages died on line which contains "session_start()";

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about what you really want to do here.. but i guess you could do this..

```
<?php
  $perform_check = 1; #Checks data with ID : 1
  while(true) : ?>
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        data: //your data to be passed to ajax script..
        url: //the script wherein you want to run the query..
        onSuccess: function(data) {

             if(data==test) {
             //if you have data that you want then you could stop the loop
              <?php $perform_check = false; ?>

             }

        }
    });
  <?php endwhile: ?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to edit another pages from page with infinite loop, I want to make changes on page with infinite loop :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check very often you should use a CRON that calls the function you use to check.

Comment: Basically I need to perform some actions every 3-5 seconds while user is on the website. The CRON Jobs won't help here, because each user will have different functions to update and so on...but thanks for the sugestion.

Comment: Use ajax then, and setInterval. That way your server wont carry the weight

Comment: Do you really think that if each user will send requests with ajax each some seconds will be better option?

Comment: I dont really know why you want to do that, but If you have 100 users and a weird infinite loop for each of them, then yes.Use ajax, the browser will do the work, your server will just check. Maybe I dont understand what you really want and there is better way to do so

Comment: I tried ajax but browser slows down because of setInterval. I changed Interval to 3 Seconds, then I opened HTTP Live Headers, and it seems that it sends too much requests to the server. If only there was a way to keep the same connection on multiple requests, then ajax will be the best option.